# Scala operator notation

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Although i am comfortable with the code, i am not sure how to understand what is going on under the hood and would like some help to deconstruct it

```
((1 to 10) fold "") ((s1, s2) => s"$s1 - $s2")
```

Of course using fold is not the issue, it is the postfix notation that i do not understand. Is it actually a postfix notation ?

I can see that

```
((1 to 10) fold "") (_)
```

works. Which is the partially applied function. But the notation does not look familiar to me. Hence if someone could deconstruct the operator notation usage that would help.

Comment: Humble opinion, nobody liked nor understood that syntax _(and I believe it was deprecated in some point, or is going to be deprecated in Scala 3)_. Just write it like `(1 to 10).fold("")((s1, s2) => s"$s1 - $s2")` or like `(1 to 10).fold("") { case (s1, s2) => s"$s1 - $s2" }`

Comment: There is nothing postfix here. `fold` is used as binary infix operator between `(1 to 10)` and `""`. Otherwise, I have to agree with Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez: just use `.fold(...)`.

Comment: I agree with both of ya. I would not write things that way. Just curious to know how is something possible in a language and what’s formal underpinning

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, fixity is now specified [using an annotation](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/operators.html#the-infix-annotation) in Scala 3, so you can still get infix notation when it makes sense, but otherwise it will be consistently applied.